# How to authenticate user through google app

Tags: openid, google-openid

**Any body knows how to resolve this
 i m getting  this error**

Unable to find google openid endpoint

Answer (score 1):

Endpoint for Google Apps OpenId is:
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd={YOUR-DOMAIN}